# USB device not showing up in ubuntu in VMware workstation

Tags: usb, vmware

I am using `ubuntu 16.04` installed using `VMware workstation` on windows 7. I have installed `VMware workstation` on `E drive` of my system. I want to use USB drive in ubuntu. USB is showing and working fine in windows 7 but not showing up in ubuntu.

I have tried many ways listed in other answers like enabling the `show all USB input devices` in the settings of VMware but still USB drive is not showing up. Please help.